# Aframe physics sphere breaks into smaller spheres on collision

Tags: collision-detection, game-physics, aframe, cannon.js

In my game, I make a sphere (created using a-sphere), a dynamic body, collide with another dynamic body (a-box).

Upon collision, the sphere breaks into multiple smaller spheres. I need to stop this disintegration

Here is the codepen - [sphere breaks on collision with dynamic body](https://codepen.io/nirajupadhyay11/pen/VByQOJ?editors=1011)

Here is the accompanying code -

HTML

```
<a-scene physics="debug: true; gravity: -5.0">
  <a-entity camera="userHeight: 1.6"
                look-controls
                kinematic-body>
        <a-entity cursor
                  position="0 0 -1"
                  geometry="primitive: circle; radius: 0.01; segments: 4;"
                  material="color: #FF4444; shader: flat"></a-entity>
    <a-entity position="0 0 1" id="attachment"></a-entity>
  </a-entity>

  <a-entity geometry="primitive: box; height:2" material="color: black; shader: flat" position="0 2 -5" dynamic-body></a-entity>

  <a-plane static-body color="#ccc" height="100" width="100" position="0 -0.1 0" rotation="-90 0 0"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

and JS

```
const scene = document.querySelector('a-scene');
const camera = document.querySelector('[camera]');
const attachment = document.querySelector('#attachment');

function spawnBullet() {
    let entity = document.createElement('a-sphere');
    let impulseAmount = 8;

    entity.setAttribute('radius', 1);
    // Set initial position of projectile to that of the camera.
    entity.setAttribute('position', camera.getAttribute('position'));
    entity.setAttribute('color', '#00FFCC');
    entity.setAttribute('shader', 'flat');
    entity.setAttribute('mass', 10);

    // Append projectile to the scene, not to the camera, to
    // avoid all sorts of complications. Most notably, CANNON.js
    // has no scene graph or nesting.
    scene.appendChild(entity);

    entity.setAttribute('dynamic-body', true);  

    entity.addEventListener('body-loaded', function(){
      // Can't apply forces during the same tick that attaches the body, because
      // it hasn't been fully synced to the physics sim. (bug)
      setTimeout(function () {
        let pStart = new CANNON.Vec3();
        // Use an origin point behind the head, not at the head, so
        // there's a useful vector between the origin and the projectile.
        pStart.copy(attachment.object3D.getWorldPosition());
        let force = entity.body.position.vsub(pStart);
        force.normalize(); 
        force.scale(impulseAmount, force);
        entity.body.applyImpulse(force, entity.body.position);
      }, 0);

      entity.addEventListener('collide', function(e){
        console.log("hit");
      })
    });
}

if (scene.hasLoaded) init(); // change 2
else scene.addEventListener('loaded', init);

function init () {
  // any code that appends things to the scene
  scene.addEventListener('click', spawnBullet);
}
```

Is there a way that this can be stopped and the sphere remains intact after collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listening for the `click` event on the scene is backfiring, because you get three events
- the cursor emits one when clicked on something
- the `target` emits one when clicked
- the canvas emits one (mouse clicking, not the a-frame cursor - on the DOM canvas element).

You can see it in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vh7yx5c8/21/) example, click on any object on the scene, and check out the console.

---

You can listen for the `mousedown` event which is emitted by the cursor everytime its "clicked". Check it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vh7yx5c8/25/)

---

Provided you're on a PC, you can also listen for the click on the aframe canvas. If you're on a `vive` then just call the `shootBullet` when a trigger is pulled.

Check it out working properly [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwvOeW?editors=1011).

Answer (score 2):

The sphere is not breaking, what's happening is that your `click` event handler is being called multiple times for each click, and creating many spheres at once. I'm not entirely sure why that's happening. One way around that, use `AFRAME.utils.throttle` to prevent creating spheres too quickly:

```
spawnBullet = AFRAME.utils.throttle(spawnBullet, 100);
scene.addEventListener('click', spawnBullet);
```

Updating to a newer version of A-Frame may also fix the issue.